# How to set Bamboo variables from Powershell/Other scripts?

Tags: powershell, teamcity, bamboo

In TeamCity using their [**Service Message**](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) feature, one can set value to TeamCity variables from any script environment:

```
echo ##teamcity[foo 'booya']
```

If you run this in batch/Powershell, we can set TeamCity variable **foo** to *booya*.

How can I do something similar like this in Bamboo? I would like to format build number in certain way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

this feature is not available in bamboo. It's an open feature request.

https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/BAM-10282

I deal with this by outputting an html build info page with build artifacts.   This includes bamboo number and our actual number. It also links back to bamboo site.

Hth

Av